# How to check does not exists properties in nested json

Tags: json, properties, nested

my json structure is:

```
     { 
       "bob":   {"blue": 2 }
 }
```

next i did this for checking does not exists properties:

```
     if(myArray['alice']['red] === false) {
        console.log('undefined');
     }
```

then it returns "Cannot read property 'red' of undefined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code:

```
var arr = { 
   "bob":   {"blue": 2 }
}

if(!arr['alice']) {
    console.log('undefined');
}
else if (!arr['alice']['red']) {
    console.log('undefined');
}
```

Comment: @user3698126, sorry, my mistake. i updated the code. please try again.